# Union causing an ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, oracle10g, oracle11g

With the following query as an example:

```
  select p.product_id, p.product_name, 
     product_type as product_type,
      from products
    group by p.product_id, p.product_name
  union
    select p.product_id, p.product_name, 
     cast(collect(coalesce(product_type, decode(product_description,null,'DESCR' || '-' product_description) as my_type) as product_type,
    from products
    group by p.product_id, p.product_name
```

The select statement in the first query returns product_type as a varchar and on the second query product_type is of type my_type. 
This is causing and ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression because the data types are not the same.

Is it possible to cast product_type on the first query to be of type my_type?

I tried changing the first query as shown below but with no luck.

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, 
     cast(product_type as my_type) as product_type,
     decode(product_source_location, null, 'NO_SOURCE', product_source_location)
    from products
    group by p.product_id, p.product_name
```

### Edit

my_type is defined as `'TYPE "my_type" AS TABLE OF varchar2(4000)'`

Comment: Is it possible?  What happened when you tried?  If not, can you run a to_char on the my_type field?

Comment: When i tried it, it gave me an [1]: ORA-00902: invalid datatype error.

Comment: my_type is defined as 'TYPE "my_type" AS TABLE OF varchar2(4000)'

Comment: I doubt that the first SELECT is correct, since neither `product_type` nor `product_source_location` are part of the GROUP BY.

Comment: I have corrected the query.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why would you want the product_type as a string and as a table type (which maybe always only has one row, if product_id is unique) in separate rows in the result set? If you really need both can you pull them as two columns and not have the union at all? I'm missing something...!

Comment: The query is just an example of what i am trying to achieve. The actual query that i am working with is quite huge and cant really post it here. The general idea is just i want to merge two queries where one of them has a column that is a TABLE type and the other doesnt.

Comment: Do they have to be in the same position - can you have an extra column for the table type which you leave null in the other part of the union? (Or if null doesn't work, a collected dummy value, maybe).

Comment: The java code that reads this column uses the specific column position. If i make the positions different i will have to change the client code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do such casting in SQL. But in PL/SQL you can:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255)
/

DECLARE
  tab STRARRAY;
  cnt NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO cnt
   FROM TABLE(CAST(tab AS strarray));
  dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
END;
/
```

I think I was wrong in my assumptions above. I did not delete that as it is still valid example. Below example casting existing table column (emp table) with COLLECT as type of table_type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchar2_ntt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

SELECT deptno
    , CAST(COLLECT(ename) AS varchar2_ntt) AS emps
  FROM   scott.emp
GROUP  BY deptno
/

-- This is dumb but works:

SELECT deptno
     , CAST(COLLECT(ename) AS varchar2_ntt) AS emps
  FROM   scott.emp
 GROUP  BY deptno
 UNION ALL
 SELECT deptno
     , CAST(COLLECT(ename) AS varchar2_ntt) AS emps
   FROM   scott.emp
  GROUP  BY deptno
 /
```

Comment: Thanks. I am running this query using JDBC so cant use PL/SQL

Comment: What if you made it a stored procedure?

Comment: Your casting example is exactly what i am doing in the second query on the union. The problem is that you cant then union that query with column that returns a varchar. I tried converting to a clob using to_Clob but the data types are inconsistent.

Comment: @ziggy - Please post your sample structures. I maybe able to help you more. Try UNION ALL and group by. Please see my example.

Comment: @Art ok i tried with Union All and that seems to work. It doesn't like it with Union on its own. I dont expect there to be duplicates so Union All should be ok. Thanks.