# Is it possible to convert a varchar2 column to a user defined type?

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a type declared as

```
TYPE "TABLE_TYPE" AS TABLE OF varchar2(4000)
```

How can i convert a column i am selecting in a query to return that type.

For example

```
Select cast(to_char(sysdate) as TABLE_TYPE) from dual
```

Returns an `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CHAR` error. Is there a way to convert a column which is a varchar2 to be of the user defined type?

Comment: wow, you're busy today ziggy ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to return a collection with a single element, you would just need to call the type's constructor

```
SQL> create type table_type as table of varchar2(100);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> select table_type( to_char( sysdate ))
  2    from dual;

TABLE_TYPE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TABLE_TYPE('14-FEB-13')
```

Normally, though, when you are creating a collection, the intent is to populate it with multiple elements by running a query that returns multiple rows.  For that, you would want to do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_strs table_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT ename
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_strs
    FROM emp;
  <<l_strs now contains 1 element for each row in the EMP table>>
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use cast + multiset

```
select cast(multiset(
    select to_char(sysdate-level, 'YYYYMMDD')
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10
) as t_vchar_tab)
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Union causing an ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879364/union-causing-an-ora-01790-expression-must-have-same-datatype-as-corresponding/14879664#14879664)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchar2_ntt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

SELECT deptno
    , CAST(COLLECT(ename) AS varchar2_ntt) AS emps
  FROM   scott.emp
GROUP  BY deptno
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select table_type(to_char(sysdate)) from dual;
```